# Browser caches the rewrited url. How to stop it from being cached?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, cache

I'm using nginx to rewrite a url

```
location /ReeferUI/Reports/ {
       rewrite ^ /ReeferUI/index.html break;
       proxy_pass  http://localhost:8083/ReeferUI;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
      }
```

It is working fine but it is caching the index.html which I don't want.

How can I prevent browser from caching redirection url?

Comment: If you don't want content to be cached, set the appropriate cache control headers.

Comment: @HBruijn Can you suggest how to do that, I am new to nginx.